# 20.04 pulseaudio weirdness at boot and unix sockets

Tags: pulseaudio, 20.04, 19.10

I have a working pulseaudio setup for Ubuntu 19.10 in which the default sink is set to onboard intel and module-native-protocol-unix is set to a socket with auth-anon.

This same setup in 20.04 behaves very weirdly, if I run that config at boot it claims the sink does not exist and that buggers the whole thing up. Killing Pulse does not work however If I boot with just sink part of the default.pa it still complains it can't find it at boot but killing pulse it returns perfectly happy and then finds the sink.
I can then change on the live system to having the original config file restart pulse and it works perfectly, socket created, default sink still functional.

I can't figure out what has changed between the two releases or why this only matters if the configuration is in place at boot.

Ok fixed the default sink - for some reason this version of pulse/ubuntu needs its hand holding with set card profile first so it can then find the card by name, and use it at boot. Though after the system is live changing the conf over works perfectly. Where the previous version found the just the name alsa_card.pci## enough at boot.

The unix sockets I think I have found a clue - for some reason the socket created by the same systemwide pulse config on the working install is owned by the user and the none working by gdm (can't believe it too me this long to check that). Thought it was more than just a clue but now I'm even more confused as in the fiddling with chown etc it started working, and now i can't fiddle it back into life at all...

Ok I know how to make it live again by manually starting pulseaudio with -vv flags. For some reason that works, where the autospawned pulse or just started manually with pulseaudio --start fail with the following showing when probing their status.

```
Jun 05 00:10:24 Archive pulseaudio[2637]: bind(): Address already in use
Jun 05 00:10:24 Archive pulseaudio[2637]: Failed to load module "module-native-protocol-unix" (argument: "auth-anonymous=1 socket=/tmp/pulse-socket"): initialization failed.
```

Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK finally got the time to figure out a fix.
For some reason the creator of a pulse Unix socket matters (even though its all permissions for everyone). And Gnome is running pulse at startup - using the system config by default with some extra bits. So simply commenting out the use system conf (or giving it a bespoke config i suppose - don't think I get prelogin sounds with the commenting out) in /var/lib/gdm3/.config/pulse/default.pa fixes this issue.

I expect this is a bug/ overzealous security feature in pulse's start up - it can't create the file because it exists, and won't use it because it didn't create it. Why restarting pulse with -v flags will work and just --start won't does confuse me a little though - with the -v flags it does overwrite the socket - so I presume either it doesn't check and abort or it does a cleanup step first in verbose mode. But I've not looked through Pulse's code at all.